# JQuery $(this).append not working

Tags: jquery, xml, dom, xml-parsing, append

If I append directly to XmlDoc it works but if append to $(this) not showing up. Any idea why it is failing. Below is my code

```
            $(".save").click(function () {
                var xml = $('#xmlnavs').val(),
                    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                    $xml = xmlDoc;
                    var sXml = '<navigation><name>' + $('#navigation').val() + '</name><id>' + items + '</id>' + '<order>' + $('#order').val() + '</order>' + '</navigation>';
                    if ($('#nav-parent').find("option:selected").val() != '---SELECT---') {
                        $(xml).find("navigation").each(function () {
                            if ($(this).find('name').text() == $('#nav-parent').find("option:selected").val()) {
                                if ($(this).find('subnavigations').length) {
                                    //THE BELOW LINE NOT UPDATING TO XML DOC
                                    $(this).find('subnavigations').append(sXml);
                                } else {
                                    //THE BELOW LINE NOT UPDATING TO XML DOC
                                    sXml = '<subnavigations><navigation><name>' + $('#navigation').val() + '</name><id>' + items + '</id>' + '<order>' + $('#order').val() + '</order>' + '</navigation></subnavigations>';
                                    $(this).append(sXml);
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                         //BUT THIS WORKS
                        $(xmlDoc).find('navigations').append(sXml);
                    }
                    $('#xmlnavs').val(xmlToString(xmlDoc));
                    xml = $('#xmlnavs').val(),
                        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                        $xml = xmlDoc;

            });
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all your support guest271314 helped me fix this below is the change

old code

```
$(xml).find('navigation').each(function (a, b) {
```

new code

$(xmlDoc).find('navigation').each(function (a, b) {

Comment: Do you have a DOM tag called `subnavigations` : `<subnavigations></subnavigations>`?

Comment: Are you actually getting to that line of code?

Comment: Can you include your HTML? Try to console $(this) in that context, to make sure it's pointing to the right element.

Comment: @Karl I am using string xml to jquery append function which accepts xml string as input. No subnavigations does not exist in DOM

Comment: @GeneParcellano I have debugged through console, it is stepping into that line $(this).append

Comment: @Gene the code is in my localhost yet to publish, so I cant share html

Comment: See 

`var xml = $('#xmlnavs').val()` 

`$xml = xmlDoc;`

"THE BELOW LINE NOT UPDATING TO XML DOC" .

Tried `$xmlDoc.find().each()` instead of `$(xml).find().each()` ?

Comment: @guest271314, thanks for pointing out the issue, i was about to bang my head into the wall, you are life saver :)